# Mysql function 1064 error

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-error-1064

The below works for me with older versions of MySQL.

But I have no idea where the problem can be.

**Params:**

```
aId - int usigned
sId - int usigned
```

**Function:**

```
BEGIN

DECLARE test decimal;

SELECT lft into @myLeft FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT rgt into @myRight FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT (rgt - lft + 1) into @myWidth FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;

SELECT sum(value) as v into test FROM `vw_accounts` 
WHERE lft 
BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight AND subjectId = sId;

RETURN test;

END
```

**Error:**

```
The following query has failed: "CREATE FUNCTION `get_all_money_account`(`aId` INT UNSIGNED, `sId` INT UNSIGNED) RETURNS DECIMAL(decimal(12,2)) COMMENT 'vrátí součet všech účtů pod vybraným' NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN

DECLARE test DECIMAL;

SELECT lft into @myLeft FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT rgt into @myRight FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT (rgt - lft + 1) into @myWidth FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;

SELECT sum(value) as v into test FROM `vw_accounts` 
WHERE lft 
BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight AND subjectId = sId;

RETURN test;

END"
```

**Old script:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_all_money_account`(`aId` INT(10) UNSIGNED, `sId` INT(10) UNSIGNED) RETURNS decimal(12,2)
    READS SQL DATA
    COMMENT 'vrátí součet všech účtů pod vybraným'
BEGIN

DECLARE test float;

SELECT lft into @myLeft FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT rgt into @myRight FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT (rgt - lft + 1) into @myWidth FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;

SELECT sum(value) as v into test FROM `vw_accounts` 
WHERE lft 
BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight AND subjectId = sId;

RETURN test;
END
```

Comment: Working code:
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION get_all_money_account(aId INT(10) UNSIGNED, sId INT(10) UNSIGNED) RETURNS decimal(12,2) DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'vrátí součet všech účtů pod vybraným'
BEGIN 

DECLARE test float;

SELECT lft into @myLeft FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT rgt into @myRight FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;
SELECT (rgt - lft + 1) into @myWidth FROM `vw_accounts` WHERE accountId = aId;

SELECT sum(value) as v into test FROM `vw_accounts` 
WHERE lft 
BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight AND subjectId = sId;

RETURN test;
END //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Can you tell us which versions it works for and which it doesn't? Saying it works for older versions when you specify no versions isn't particularly useful. Also, don't post code in comments, [edit] the question instead and add the information there (unless it's meant to be an answer, in which case you should post it in the answer section and explain the problem and fix).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making a self-join instead?

```
SELECT SUM(b.value)
FROM   vw_accounts a
  JOIN vw_accounts b ON b.lft BETWEEN a.lft AND a.rgt
WHERE  a.accountId = ?
   AND b.subjectId = ?
```